# NuGet package version and NuGet Id

Tags: .net, nuget, teamcity, octopus-deploy, assemblyinfo

I have one *Project.sln* in my GitRepo.  And I need to build 4 NuGet packages with different configurations (*local*, *qa*, *sandbox* and *production*).  I'm using TeamCity with Octopus Deploy.

In TeamCity my Build Configuration has the following Build Steps:

```
1) NuGet Installer
2) Build Project.sln with *Local* Configuration
3) NuGet Pack with using .csproj file

4) NuGet Installer
5) Build Project.sln with *QA* Configuration
6) NuGet Pack with using .csproj file

7) NuGet Installer
8) Build Project.sln with *Sandbox* Configuration
9) NuGet Pack with using .csproj file

10) NuGet Installer
11) Build Project.sln with *Production* Configuration
12) NuGet Pack with using .csproj file
```

And I have the following problems:

1) When I'm using *AssemblyInfo patcher* it makes only one NuGet package file. On step number 3 TeamCity creates a package with name *2.2.1.%build.counter%*. And on step number 6 it creates a package with the same name and overwrites it. It does the same on steps 9 and 12.  Finally I have only one NuGet package with last configuration (in my case it's *Production*).

I want to have 4 packages like:

```
2.2.1.%build.counter%_local
2.2.1.%build.counter%_qa
2.2.1.%build.counter%_sandbox
2.2.1.%build.counter%_production
```

2) The next problem is with Octopus. When TeamCity makes packages (it makes 4 packages, but without *AssemblyInfo patcher*), it makes them with the same id (Project) and when I'm trying to Deploy "some" (let it be QA) package to the QA environment, Octopus asks me to select the *id* of a NuGet package. And it only sees one *id* - "*Project*".  I think it is the last package created by TeamCity.

Comment: For your problem with Octopous deploy, you just need to make sure you are using a suitable package name that differentiates between environments, so instead of `2.2.1.%build.counter%.` you should be using `2.2.1.%build.counter%-qa` etc.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to create TeamCity configuration for each NuGet package you need. Or patch and build manually instead of build-in NuGet support.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your goal by creating nuget packages (nuget pack step) from  .nuspec files.

Here is the most common example of this file (1 of 4 in your case)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <metadata xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2010/07/nuspec.xsd">
    <id>yourProcjectName.qa</id>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <authors>Jay Hamlin</authors>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>Simple Description</description>
  </metadata>
  <files>
    <file src="bin\Release\*.dll" target="lib" />
  </files>
</package>
```

1. First of all in 'id' section specify **custom nuget package id**.
2. 'Version' section could be override by TeamCity property. Here is example:

[image]

3. Nuget pack will create package and name it from template: {package_id}.{version}.nupkg (or {version}.{package_id}.nupkg - I don't remember)
4. Now you must simply publish your packages to octopus nuget server. Package will have the same name as id, so if you create 4 different .nuspec configurations you will have 4 packages with diffrent names but same version.

Ps. You can check your nuspec files by opening them in nuget package explorer ( [LINK](https://github.com/NuGetPackageExplorer/NuGetPackageExplorer) )